# Visual Studio (2010): Is there a shortcut key to toggle all open tool windows?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, macros, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to hide/show all open tool windows in Visual Studio 2010?  I'm aware that I can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to go into full screen mode, but that doesn't help me much.

I'm interested primarily because I'm data copying from PDF tables to an XML document using Windows 7's <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> side-by-side windows feature (which is why full screen won't cut it).  I realize I could have hidden all the windows by the time I get an answer, but it would be useful to know.

I'm also open to the option of a plugin/macro that would toggle them all too.

Comment: Ironically, as I was writing this question I couldn't but wish there was a keyboard shortcut to wrap `<kbd></kbd>` around some text in SO's editor :-)

Comment: Alt + W + U Auto hides all Windows, but no way to undo...

Answer (score 3):

For some reason I can't comment, but just do what I do and use auto-hide. 90% of the time it works, for the other 10% it has a nice tendency to not disappear. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Comments aren't allowed until you have 50 (I think) rep.  +1 to get you there a bit quicker.  I actually prefer the tool windows to be visible when I'm working with a maximized window.  This is actually the solution I'd come up with whilst waiting for an answer, it's just tedious to have to un-Auto-Hide everything again afterwards.  I don't like using my mouse much :-)

Comment: Yeah, I can sympathise with you there. I looked it up for a bit but that seems like a bit too much versatility to ask from good ol' VS. Good luck anyway